Polynomials with rational roots
For a given integer $n$, is it possible to choose polynomials $f,g,h \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $n$ with $\gcd(f,g)=1$, so that $h = f+g$ and each of $f,g$ and $h$ have $n$ rational roots?
This is of course trivial to do when $n = 1$, and when $n = 2$ you can pick $f,g,h$ using pythagorean triples so that each of $f,g,h$ can be factored using difference of squares (for example $f = 9x^2-1$, $g = 16x^2$, $h = 25x^2-1$). Note that this is also trivial if we allow $f$ and $g$ to share factors, since then we can simply pick any $f$ with all rational roots and let $g = 2f$ and $h = 3f$.
However, for higher degrees $n$ there isn't a nice class of polynomials (that I'm aware of at least!) with such a simple criterion for splitting completely over $\mathbb{Q}$ like difference of squares. I am particularly interested in the case when $n$ is a power of $2$, but haven't been able to use that extra information to any real benefit.
Update:
Just to generalize @Chris Lewis from the comments, if $f = (Ax^2-B)^2$ and $g = -(Cx^2-D)^2$ then we can factor $f+g$ as a difference of squares to
$$\left((A+C)x^2-(B+D)\right)\left((A-C)x^2-(B-D)\right)$$
Both of these are in turn factorable as differences of squares if we pick $A,B,C,D$ so that $A\pm C$ and $B\pm D$ are all squares. Writing $A-C = j^2$ for any choice of $j$, then $C = A-j^2$. Then for any square $k^2$ (with the same parity as $j^2$) we can pick $A$ so that $A+C = 2A-j^2 = k^2$, or so that $2A = j^2+k^2$. By symmetry we can do the same thing for $B$ and $D$ with squares $(j')^2$ and $(k')^2$. Of course, we also need to ensure that each of $A,B,C,D$ are squares themselves, so that $f$ and $g$ can split completely. If we set $k=k’=1$ I believe this can be accomplished by using solutions to the negative Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=1$ and it’s negative $x^2-y^2=-1$.
Chris Lewis' example is the specific case $A = 25, C = 24, B=1, D = 0$. Note that $25 \pm 24$ give you two squares and $1\pm 0$ gives you two squares. Also note that $(7,5)$ and $(1,0)$ give solutions to Pell’s two equations. This gives a rich family of solutions when $n=4$.

For clarity, are $f$, $g$ and $h$ allowed to have $n$ rational roots by having roots with higher multiplicity? Your quadratic example seems to suggest yes.

It would be useful to have an answer to @Servaes' question. If it's allowed (which I also assume is the case based on $g(x)$ in the example), then a quartic solution would be $f(x)=-576x^4$, $g(x)=\left(25x^2-1\right)^2$ giving $h(x)=49x^4-50x^2+1$ with roots $\pm1$ and $\pm\frac17$. It might be possible to extend this idea further to other $n$.

@Serves, Yes higher multiplicity is absolutely allowed!

For $n=3$ it is possible to construct such examples directly. We can write $f=(x-a_1)(x-b_1)(x-c_1)$ and $g=(x-a_2)(x-b_2)(x-c_2)$, and $h=2(x-a_3)(x-b_3)(x-c_3)$. Then the equation $h=f+g$ is equivalent to three polynomial equations in the nine variables $a_i,b_i,c_i$, for $i=1,2,3$. It turns out that there are many rational solutions with $\gcd(f,g)=1$. One integral example is given as follows:
\begin{align*}
f & = (x-2)(x-3)(x - 133),\\
g & = (x+2)(x+3)(x+21),\\
h & = 2(x-1)(x-7)(x-48).
\end{align*}
This suggests that we can solve it also for $n>3$, but it remains to find a "nice class" of rational solutions.

Thank you! This does look intriguing. My only fear is that while there is a lot of freedom (i.e. you'll always have $3n$ variables and only $n$ equations) the resulting equations are quite complicated and non-linear. I've been trying to think if Lagrange interpolation is a good approach because note that if $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are the zeros of $h$ then $f(a_i) = -g(a_i) = b_i$ for any $b_i$ we choose in $\mathbb{Q}$ and we can recover $f$ and $g$. The question becomes choosing $b_i$ nicely so that both $f$ and $g$ split completely over the rationals.

if you don’t mind me asking what software did you use to solve the above system and how did you restrict to rational solutions? Did you just use a Mathematica solver?

Yes, I computed a Groebner basis, and then just assigned some of the $9$ variables by integers. Then the remaining ones are given by rational formulas. For example, let $a_1=1,b_1=2$, $a_2=-1,b_2=-2$. Then there are very many rational solutions, e.g., $f=(x-1)(x-2)(3x+11)$, $g=(x+1)(x+2)(3x-11)$ with $h=f+g=6x(x+3)(x-3)$. This solution should generalize for all $n\ge 3$. I tried it for $n=4$, and this also works.
